# php mysqli prepared statement search result pagination, link to next page show empty

Tags: php, mysqli, pagination

solved ..basically as hinted by YourCommonSense, using the get variable to pass through the search query so i added these chunck of code in on top and edited the linkable url to passthrough the variable.

```
if (isset($_GET['searchquery'])){
    $searchquery=$_GET['searchquery'];
$stmt = $myConnection->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ?');
        $param = "%$searchquery%";
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $param, $param, $param, $param, $param);
        $stmt->execute();
        /* store result */
    $result=$stmt->bind_result($id);
    $rows=array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $rows[]=array(
            'id' => $id
        );
    }
    $rows=$id;
    // This is the number of results we want displayed per page
    $page_rows = 4;
    // This tells us the page number of our last page
    $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
    // This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
    if($last < 1){
        $last = 1;
    }
    // Establish the $pagenum variable
    $pagenum = 1;
    // Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
    if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
        $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
    }
    // This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
    if ($pagenum < 1) { 
        $pagenum = 1; 
    } else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
        $pagenum = $last; 
    }

    $stmt=$myConnection->prepare('SELECT id,product_name,price FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? LIMIT ?,?');
$begin= ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows;
$end= $page_rows;
$stmt->bind_param('sssssii', $param, $param, $param, $param, $param,$begin,$end);
$stmt->execute();
/* store result */
        $stmt->store_result();
        /* get the row count */
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;
    if ($count >= 1) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $product_name, $price);
            $search_output = "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";       

$textline1 = "<h4><center>Total of <b>$rows</b> items in this section</center></h4>";
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
// If there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to 
       the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we
       generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="http://www.chenlikonlinestore.com/search.php?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
    $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?searchquery='.$searchquery.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }
    // Render the target page number, but without it being a link
    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
    // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?searchquery='.$searchquery.'&pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?searchquery='.$searchquery.'&pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
    }
}
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                "$id, $product_name, $price";
                $search_output .= "
                <li><div class='product'>
                <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='info'>
                <span class='holder'>
                <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg' alt='$product_name' />
                <span class='book-name'>$product_name</span>
                </a>
                 <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='buy-btn'>RM<span class='price'>$price</span></a>
                </div>
                </li>

                ";
            }
        }
}
```

as mentioned in the question, i try to do my search result paginated. Everything else work, but the last little bit is when I click my paginatedCrls button go to next page or specific page, i loaded and show as a fresh new search. how do i fix this?

```
<?php
session_start();

$search_output = "";
if (empty($searchquery)) 
{ $search_output = "<hr />Please enter a search term in the above search box <hr />";}

if (isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != "") {
    $searchquery = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\/\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    if ($_POST['filter1'] == "Products") {
        require_once ("storescripts/connect_to_mysqli.php");
 $stmt = $myConnection->prepare('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ?');
        $param = "%$searchquery%";
        $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $param, $param, $param, $param, $param);
        $stmt->execute();
        /* store result */
    $result=$stmt->bind_result($id);
    $rows=array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $rows[]=array(
            'id' => $id
        );
    }
    $rows=$id;
    // This is the number of results we want displayed per page
    $page_rows = 4;
    // This tells us the page number of our last page
    $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
    // This makes sure $last cannot be less than 1
    if($last < 1){
        $last = 1;
    }
    // Establish the $pagenum variable
    $pagenum = 1;
    // Get pagenum from URL vars if it is present, else it is = 1
    if(isset($_GET['pn'])){
        $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
    }
    // This makes sure the page number isn't below 1, or more than our $last page
    if ($pagenum < 1) { 
        $pagenum = 1; 
    } else if ($pagenum > $last) { 
        $pagenum = $last; 
    }

    $stmt=$myConnection->prepare('SELECT id,product_name,price FROM products WHERE product_name LIKE ? OR details LIKE ? OR category LIKE ? OR subcategory LIKE ? OR price LIKE ? LIMIT ?,?');
$begin= ($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows;
$end= $page_rows;
$stmt->bind_param('sssssii', $param, $param, $param, $param, $param,$begin,$end);
$stmt->execute();
/* store result */
        $stmt->store_result();
        /* get the row count */
        $count = $stmt->num_rows;
    if ($count >= 1) {
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $product_name, $price);
            $search_output = "<hr />$count results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";       

$textline1 = "<h4><center>Total of <b>$rows</b> items in this section</center></h4>";
$textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";
// Establish the $paginationCtrls variable
$paginationCtrls = '';
// If there is more than 1 page worth of results
if($last != 1){
    /* First we check if we are on page one. If we are then we don't need a link to 
       the previous page or the first page so we do nothing. If we aren't then we
       generate links to the first page, and to the previous page. */
    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="http://www.chenlikonlinestore.com/search.php?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a> &nbsp; &nbsp; ';
        // Render clickable number links that should appear on the left of the target page number
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
    $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
            }
        }
    }
    // Render the target page number, but without it being a link
    $paginationCtrls .= ''.$pagenum.' &nbsp; ';
    // Render clickable number links that should appear on the right of the target page number
    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a> &nbsp; ';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    // This does the same as above, only checking if we are on the last page, and then generating the "Next"
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= ' &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a> ';
    }
}
            while ($stmt->fetch()) {
                "$id, $product_name, $price";
                $search_output .= "
                <li><div class='product'>
                <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='info'>
                <span class='holder'>
                <img src='inventory_images/$id.jpg' alt='$product_name' />
                <span class='book-name'>$product_name</span>
                </a>
                 <a href='product.php?id=$id' class='buy-btn'>RM<span class='price'>$price</span></a>
                </div>
                </li>

                ";
            }
        } else {
            $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
        }

    } else {
        $search_output = "<hr />0 results for <strong>$searchquery</strong><hr />";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: even without reading the question body I would tell that **you aren't passing the search terms to the next page**

Comment: the amount of security issues ans messy code is too damn high!

Comment: how to pass the search terms to the next page? session it? i am real begginer

Comment: exactly the same way you are passing the page number

Comment: suddenly i realise now..fixing

Comment: just one hint: you have to encode your parameters properly. http_build_query() function is indispensable for that

Comment: what do you mean by http_build_query? I manage to sort it but go the long way?? i am posting the code up..also regarding the security issue, anything to improve on?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

pass the 'searchquery' variable through from the url and get it back from the script

Comment: AN interesting thing. 2 too hastily accepted answers from the same user... Especially this one, due to it's exceptional quality

Comment: haha my account get blocked to ask question from my first account thus asking in new account and thought, erm may be by accepting the answer can revive this account

Answer (score -1):

1. Learn MVC
2. You only pass the pagenumber to you pagination controlls, not the searchquery
3. Dont use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`
4. Use proper escaping methods or validators instead of those `preg_replaces` to filter input